# Django : Doesn't apply an automatic id field to table

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I'm working on a project that has new data coming in every 24 hours. Weather sensor data. To test things locally, I'm importing the data into a new table that I make in postgresql.

After creating the django project, I set up the database. I connected Django to my local database, without any models yet. In psql, I make a new table labeled `weather_sensors`, with several different fields. There is no id field, since Django should set that automatically.

After `python manage.py migrate` and setting a superuser, I then copy the data from the .DAT file and put that data into the table fields.

Then: `python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

I get the model from there, and put it into my models.py. Meta class managed = False, but I delete that because I want Django to manage it.

However, it wont. Django, for some reason, doesn't automatically set an id column. So when I try to view the page, it gives me an error stating that weather_sensors.id can't be found.

If I manually ALTER the table through psql and add an 'id' column, it works fine.

However, if I want to override the id, say with `'location_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)'` it gives me an error.

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 566, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: WeatherSensor has no field named 'id'
```

Ok. So let's say I drop that id field manually. I use `ALTER TABLE weather_sensors DROP COLUMN id`

I make sure my model WeatherSensor has location_id set up, then run `make migrations and migrate`. ON `migrate`, I get this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "id" does not exist
```

Ok. So let's further say that I Alter the table again and put the column "id" back in. I modify my models.py file "WeatherSensor" model to reflect this change (id field),  and `make migrations`.

However, on `migrate`, I get the WeatherSensor field error again. This time I can't seem to fix it.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 566, in get_field
    raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: WeatherSensor has no field named 'id'
```

I'm guessing I could go into the migrations and delete newer migrations, but I haven't tried that yet. As it is, I'll have to start a new project, import all the data in the table, etc.

There's gotta be someway to get Django to automatically set up the id field again after importing the data, migrating, and setting up the model. It's a big pain right now and I haven't been able to move on from this.

Thank you for your help. For your info, I am using Django 2.1 and python 3.7

***EDIT***

Regarding the most recent problem: when I come upon this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 566, in get_field
        raise FieldDoesNotExist("%s has no field named '%s'" % (self.object_name, field_name))
    django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: WeatherSensor has no field named 'id'
```

Even if I added the field and made migrations and migrated the app, it would still come up with that error. I found that if I deleted some of the old migrations, I can bypass this problem and it worked as it did before. However, this hasn't fixed the problem where Django *should* automatically add an id column in the database.

I will continue to experiment and see if I come across why this is. But, if anyone has any idea what I might be doing wrong, let me know.

Comment: Did you *migrate* the application? Normally if you add a primary key, the Django migrations will change the columns and add an extra column (and remove the other one)

Comment: Yes, as I've mentioned, I always make migrations and then migrate. Django migrations do NOT change the columns and add an extra column (and remove other ones) in this case.